# stack Label in 8086 assembly instruction set

Tags: assembly, x86-16, machine-code

I am trying to learn 8086 assembly. 
this is the stack part of a 8086 assembly code  :

```
 STACK  SEGMENT STACK
 DW 50 DUP(?)
 TOP_STACK Label Word 
 STACK  ENDS
```

what is the purpose of `TOP_STACK Label Word` ?
i couldn't find `Label` keyword in 8086 instruction set.
is this line a directive or an instruction? and what is the application of `TOP_STACK`?
is `TOP_STACK` a variable or should I use it like a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a directive of your assembler, which I assume is `masm` (you should have said so). See the [relevant page in the msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7chtfff.aspx).

The purpose is to define a pointer to the end of your stack. There is no storage allocated there, you should not use it as a variable. Presumably it will be used by the code to set up the initial stack pointer.